# How do I remove a series of matrices from an array based upon a condition?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

If I have an array defined as:

```
Q <- array(runif(48), c(4,4,3), dimnames=list(
  c("P","PO","C","T"), c("LL","RR","R","Y"), c("Jerry1", "Jerry2", "Jerry3")))
```

What I would like to do is check each "Jerry_n" matrix within the array Q at the address Q[1, 4,], and if Q[1, 4] is less than Q[1, 1, ], then I would like to remove that Jerry matrix.

Thank you so very much in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I will not go quietly into the night! :-)

Comment: That's pretty funny!!!  Thanks for the laugh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
dropmat <- Q[1,4,] < Q[1,1,]
Q <- Q[,,!dropmat]
```

should do it ...

**edit**: assigned result to original.

Comment: Hi, Ben.  This is very helpful.  To make the change stick, I just added after your solution Q <- Q[,,!dropmat].  Thank you very much for your help.  I am very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

```
Q[,,Q[1,1,]<=Q[1,4,]]
```

Is that what you want?

**EDIT:** Updated the inequality.

Comment: how is this different from my answer other than flipping the sign of the inequality (you should probably use `<=` rather than `<` if you're going to flip it in this way, i.e. `!a<b` equivalent to `b<=a`) ... ?

Comment: ups, did not see your post when I posted my answer, thought about it for some time and just answered without refreshing the webpage.